# want a query for searching products

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I've been working on this webbApp for a store and whenever I add the clause for the search it stops working on the stored procedure, if I do a simple query to the database it works.

I have a variable to store the content of the search textbox in the website called @pesq which is a varchar(50)

This is the query in question:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY prd.nome ASC)AS RowNumber, 
prd.nome as nome, prd.bpm as bpm, prd.preco as preco, 
prd.imagem as imagem, esc.nome AS escala, 
gen.nome AS genero, rtn.nome AS nota 
INTO #Results1 
FROM produtos prd
            INNER JOIN escala esc ON (prd.id_escala=esc.id_escala) 
            INNER JOIN genero gen ON (prd.id_genero=gen.id_generos) 
            INNER JOIN root_note rtn ON (prd.root_note=rtn.id_root_note)
            WHERE prd.vendido LIKE 0 AND prd.nome LIKE '%'+@pesq+'%'  

SELECT @RecordCount = COUNT(*) FROM #Results1  
SELECT * FROM #Results1 WHERE RowNumber BETWEEN(@PageIndex -1) * @PageSize + 1 AND (((@PageIndex -1) * @PageSize + 1) + @PageSize) - 1 

DROP TABLE #Results1
```

The objective is for it to return any product into the table #Results1 so I can then fill a repeater with the products in the store page
I cannot find a reason for it not to work.

I've tried multiple ways of doing the clause and none have worked.

---

I've resolved my issue.
I've declared a varchar(max) before the select, setting it with '%' + @pesq + '%'
Doing this there where no more errors
Thank you for the responses.

Comment: Hope, you can explain the logic for prd.vendido LIKE 0. I would expect prd.vendido=0

Comment: I was taught that it does the same function in WHERE clauses. For organization porpuses, I use = when I'm setting values and LIKE when I'm doing WHERE causes.

Answer (score 0):

To the secondary part of your question - any temp tables created within a stored procedure are automatically dropped when the stored procedure finishes - you don't have to take any additional actions.
Also you try using CTE instead.

```
;with cte as
(SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY prd.nome ASC)AS RowNumber, 
prd.nome as nome, prd.bpm as bpm, prd.preco as preco, 
prd.imagem as imagem, esc.nome AS escala, 
gen.nome AS genero, rtn.nome AS nota  
FROM produtos prd
            INNER JOIN escala esc ON (prd.id_escala=esc.id_escala) 
            INNER JOIN genero gen ON (prd.id_genero=gen.id_generos) 
            INNER JOIN root_note rtn ON (prd.root_note=rtn.id_root_note)
            WHERE prd.vendido LIKE 0 AND prd.nome LIKE '%'+@pesq+'%'  
)
SELECT * FROM #cte WHERE RowNumber BETWEEN(@PageIndex -1) * @PageSize + 1 AND (((@PageIndex -1) * @PageSize + 1) + @PageSize) - 1
```